# Bootstrap, how to keep middle row always contained between header row and footer row

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive

I recently added styles for `img` in this display I have for `max-height:100% and max-width:100%` which seemed ok with just the images, but I've realized that if my middle row (which can contain one or 2 side by side columns) has multiple images or an image with text around it, it completely breaks out of the row at larger resolutions.

The problem is, this page is displaying user-created content on large televisions and monitors so at that point the middle row has completely pushed the footer row out of view and the middle content is stretched down.

I don't know if it's something I should do to the middle row (or the div inside with the columns for images/text) or something different.

All I need to do is ensure that if it's a single large images, multiple images, text with an image or some other combination, that it fits inside the top and bottom rows at all times. I would be ok even if it caused my columns to end up more to the left or right respectively.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vbuf0gwL/62/

if you drag the result around 1457x781 you can really see the issue, which is why it's so bad on the large displays.

Again, the top and bottom rows should always be in view and the middle should scale accordingly

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 90vh;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal-lg {
  max-width: 80% !important;
}

.my-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.my-container>.top [class^="col-"],
.my-container>.bottom [class^="col-"] {
  background-color: #929292;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.my-container>.middle {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 30px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.my-container>.middle>* {}

#clock {
  /*background-color:#333;*/
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
  color: #fff;
}

#clock span {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

#date {
  margin-top: -10px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}

.buttonContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="https://rawgit.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/master/build/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="src/ytv.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/master/build/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.4.0/jquery.marquee.min.js'></script>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid my-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12" style="background-color:black">
        <p style="color:white">
          test
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row middle" style="flex:1; ">
      <div class="col-lg-6 leftFifty" id="leftFifty">
        <div class="leftContent" style="background-color: white; border: dotted 1px black; ">
          <p>TEST</p>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1024x942" />
          <!-- This is the div that is clicked in to select an image -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 rightFifty" id="rightFifty">
        <div class="rightContent" style="background-color: white; border: dotted 1px black; ">
          <p>TEST</p>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1024x942" />
          <!-- This is the div that is clicked in to select an image -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col-lg-12" style="background-color:black">
        <p style="color:white">
          test
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the header and footer to `position: fixed;` with the `top` and `bottom` attributes set to `0` respectively.

Comment: Will that make the image shrink with text in the middle row though? I just want to make sure that the columns in the middle row allow the content to scale inside

Comment: If you don’t apply styling to the middle element it should just scale with a scroll bar.

Comment: It's a static page on a display though, so I need the middle content to scale within  the middle row. If you check my fiddle and enlarge the resolution you can see the images go just past the footer, when they should get smaller to accommodate the text

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.. on your fiddle the middle content seems to scale as you've described you'd like it to.

Comment: No it goes beyond the footer, but I want space between the middle and footer like there is between middle and header. I want the middle row fixed between the two do if the text grows In the column the image will shrink to accommodate it

Comment: if it just has an image in it, it's fine, but if text is in there it grows too far because the image is 100% max. I was hoping I could make it so that the more text there is, the more the image would shrink to accommodate